# class 'base_controller' not found in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the below code in the controller.

```
 class Authors_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index() {
        return View::make('authors.index');
      } 
}
```

When i run in the browser, i am getting the error,

class 'base_controller' not found

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
class Authors_Controller extends Base_Controller {
```

to

```
class AuthorsController extends BaseController {
```

Edit: you might need to leave it as "Authors_Controller" depending how your file is named - but you should change it to the Laravel 4 convention of "AuthorsController"

Comment: +1 Thanks, but now i have a new error message, Class authors does not exist

Comment: @FirmView on which line do you get this error?can you post route.php code??

Comment: @FirmView probably best to look carefully at your code, particularly where you're defining your Author's class (pay attention to case `Authors != authors`), and then raise another question here if you can't work it out.. best to keep your questions as focused as possible!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to The Shift Exchange's answer. You might also want to rename your function to getIndex, and rename your controller to AuthorsController as Laravel 4 is camelCased.

Comment: +1 Thanks, but now i have a new error message, Class authors does not exist